# GWT's handler registration in second window

Tags: gwt, event-handling

I develop a multi window application with GWT by using a popup. Since Window.open() does not return a reference to the created window, i wrote my own JSNI stuff to obtain the new window's document so i can populate it. It works well, but the whole GWT event handling does not work on the widgets in the new window. At present my solution is to use JSNI for event handling. But it would be simpler if the widgets supported their GWT handlers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a popup instead of a complete new window?
I don't believe communication between different windows is directly supported in GWT.

You probably have to build or use a library to communicate via localstorage for example.

Comment: I'm using a popup window via window.open().

Comment: Consider using http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDialogBox instead of a native browser popup

Comment: The user should be able to distribute the windows across his screens so a dialog is no alternative. I don't really need communication between windows, because i control both windows with one javascript source. My current solution is working and i could accept it. It just would add some simplicity if there was a possibility to plug the open()ed window into GWT's event system.